# discard symbol of a .lib file if already exist in Windows with Visual C++

Tags: windows, visual-c++, linker

Is it possible to discard already existing symbols of a .lib file when linking with a source code ?

For example, I have a .lib file which is compiled with several source file and a **source1.cpp** file containing a function : **void function1 ()**.
I have a project containing several file, and one of his file is the same **source1.cpp** (so contains also the same functions) but which has been modified.
So is it possible to link the lib file to my project in order to take into account the source file and functions of my project instead of those of the .lib file ?

I would like to do that with Visual C++.
At the moment, when doing that I get the common error **symbol already defined...**

Thanks for your help

Comment: Is the library a static library or an import library for a DLL?

Comment: @Adrian McCarthy : it is a static library which is linked to an executable. More precisely it is an OpenGL library which I do not want to change code to avoid having a specific library. I just want to change a behaviour of 2 functions inside one of its .c file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  You should make the symbols distinct.  That is, `function1` in your project source1.cpp should have a different name than the one in your library.

Without knowing more about the situation, you might want to accomplish this by putting either the library or the project into a namespace.

```
// lib/source1.h
namespace mylib {
  void function1();
}

// lib/source1.cpp
namespace mylib {
  void function1() {
    ...
  }
}

// project/source1.h
namespace myproj {
  void function1();
}

// project/source1.cpp
namespace myproj {
  void function1() {
    ...
  }
}
```

Now in your code you can call `myproj::function1()` or `mylib::function1()`.  Those symbols will be distinct.  If you always use one and not the other, the linker will probably discard the one that's not used (at least in an optimized build).

If you don't want to change all the calls in your code, you can add a line like `using myproj::function1()`, which will tell the compiler that when you say `function1()` you mean the one from your project.

Comment: Using gcc and g++ with unix make it possible by default. But I agree that it is better to have an error than nothing to know exactly what we do. Unfortunatly I need to use exactly the same source code when using gcc/g++ and when using Visual Studio, so I can only modify linker options to succeed... or not. Furthermore, another problem is that the source1.cpp file is in fact a source1.c file, so no way to use a namespace.

Comment: @oaimac:  Just because you have to use the same source with gcc and Visual C++ doesn't limit you to linker options.  Changing the code in a way that works for both platforms (e.g., by eliminated the name collision) would solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This should not happen, an .obj in a .lib is only pulled in when it is needed.  Try writing strcpy() in your code for example, no link error even though it is also present in the CRT lib.

Do make sure that you don't need *some* of the functions in the source1.obj that's stored in the .lib.  You diagnose this by using the /verbose linker option.  Project + Properties, Linker, Command Line, Additional options box.  It shows you what symbols get pulled from the .lib, search for source1.obj.  Once it gets used, you *do* get the linker error if there's a name collision.  This is of course error prone and best avoided.

Comment: My project has to use several functions of the .lib file and my problem is that I have name collisions with the functions defined in the source1.cpp. So I would like to not take into account the symbols of the .lib file which already exists in my project.

Comment: That comment shows no hint that you even tried to do what I suggested.  Rename the functions so there's no name collision.